# Python- how to solve [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python-requests

I am trying to run this curl request that is running **successfully** from my terminal in python:

```
curl -vvv -u <user>:<password> --upload-file filePath.zip http:/someHostostName:port/pathInNexus
```

in python i wrote:

```
import requests
files = {'file': open("filePath.zip", 'rb')}
url = "http:/someHostostName:port/pathInNexus"    
response = requests.post(url,files = files ,auth=(<user>, <password>)
```

and I'm getting this error:

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='ilcebln005.corp.amdocs.com', port=8081): Max
> retries exceeded with url: pathInNexus (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x000001C2715A7CC8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
> 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it'))

I'm fairly new to curl requests and im trying to automate it at Python

Comment: It can not connect to the server. Happens with me when a site is accessible with VPN only. So in the case when the VPN is disconnected, the connection can not be made, and this exception is thrown

Comment: I'm connect to the VPN, and because of that it is working when i run the curl. the request is look ok from python? maybe I'm missing something